# Oracle - Calculation issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 4 source tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1_NAMES (NAMES VARCHAR2(12)); 

INSERT INTO TABLE1_NAMES VALUES ('JOHN');
INSERT INTO TABLE1_NAMES VALUES ('RYAN');
INSERT INTO TABLE1_NAMES VALUES ('OLAN');
INSERT INTO TABLE1_NAMES VALUES ('TONY');

CREATE TABLE TABLE2_LINES (NAMES VARCHAR2(12), LINE_NO NUMBER, UNITS NUMBER(18,4), CODE VARCHAR2(4));

INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('JOHN',1,1,'101');
INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('JOHN',2,1,'202');
INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('JOHN',3,1,'180');
INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('JOHN',4,2,'300');

INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('RYAN',1,2,'180');
INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('RYAN',2,1,'180');
INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('RYAN',3,1,'500');

INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('OLAN',1,1,'301');

INSERT INTO TABLE2_LINES VALUES ('TONY',1,1,'201');

CREATE TABLE TABLE3_DATES (NAMES VARCHAR2(12), FR_DT TIMESTAMP(3), TO_DT TIMESTAMP(3), START_DT TIMESTAMP(3),END_DT TIMESTAMP(3));

INSERT INTO TABLE3_DATES VALUES ('JOHN','01-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM','05-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM','03-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM','09-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM');
INSERT INTO TABLE3_DATES VALUES ('RYAN','01-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM','04-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM','03-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM','09-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM');
INSERT INTO TABLE3_DATES VALUES ('OLAN','01-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM','05-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM','03-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM','09-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM');

 INSERT INTO TABLE3_DATES VALUES ('TONY','01-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM','05-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM','03-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM','09-DEC-22 12.00.00.000000000 AM');

CREATE TABLE TABLE4_CODES (CD_NM VARCHAR2(12), B_CODE VARCHAR2(4), E_CODE VARCHAR2(4));
 
INSERT INTO TABLE4_CODES VALUESS ('CODELIST','100','101');
INSERT INTO TABLE4_CODES VALUESS ('CODELIST','180','180');
INSERT INTO TABLE4_CODES VALUESS ('CODELIST','200','219');
COMMIT;
```

I have 2 result tables : RESULT1_CALC, RESULT2_FINAL (one table is for calculation of total units per person and other table is the final result table which stores the person name with code)

```
CREATE TABLE RESULT1_CALC (NAMES VARCHAR2(12), FR_DT TIMESTAMP(3), TO_DT TIMESTAMP(3), START_DT TIMESTAMP(3), END_DT TIMESTAMP(3), TOT_UNITS NUMBER);

CREATE TABLE RESULT2_FINAL (NAMES VARCHAR2(12), EX_CD VARCHAR2(3));
```

Logic Explanation:

We have `TABLE2_LINES` data where we calculate `SUM(UNITS)` per person based on `CODE` value present in `TABLE4_CODES` in such a way that

1. If `180` code only is present for a person then calculate `SUM(UNITS)` and compare with formula  `TO_DT - FR_DT`, if not equal insert record (person name and `'ABC'` code) into `RESULT2_FINAL` table
2. If `180` code is present along with other eligible codes (here eligible code is nothing but code present in `TABLE4_CODES`) for a person then calculate `SUM(UNITS)` and compare with formula `END_DT - START_DT`, if not equal insert record (person name and `'ABC'` code) into `RESULT2_FINAL` table
3. If `180` code is not present but other eligible codes are present(here eligible code is nothing but code present in `TABLE4_CODES`) for a person then calculate `SUM(UNITS)` and compare with formula `END_DT - START_DT`, if not equal insert record (person name and `'ABC'` code) into `RESULT2_FINAL` table

Example:

- Case 1: For person `JOHN`, We have eligible codes i.e. `101,202, 180` (these codes present in `TABLE4_CODES` table) ..It has other eligible codes along with `180` so `SUM(UNITS)` is `3` and this value is compared with formula `TO_DT - FR_DT` i.e. December 5 - December 1 which is 4 (not equal to SUM(UNITS)) so insert into RESULT2_FINAL table.
- Case 2: For person `RYAN`, We have eligible code i.e. `180` only (this code present in `TABLE4_CODES` table) ... so `SUM(UNITS)` is `3` and this value is compared with formula `END_DT - START_DT` i.e. December 9 - December 3 which is 6 (not equal to `SUM(UNITS)`) so insert into `RESULT2_FINAL` table.
- Case 3: For person `OLAN`, we don't have eligible codes so need to do anything.
- Case 4: For person `TONY`, we have eligible code 201 but we don't have 180 so (this code present in `TABLE4_CODES` table) ... so `SUM(UNITS)` is `1` and this value is compared with formula `END_DT - START_DT` i.e. December 9 - December 3 which is 6 (not equal to `SUM(UNITS)`) so insert into `RESULT2_FINAL` table.

But in SQL query which I have mentioned below, it is not inserting person `RYAN` and also `TONY` records into `RESULT2_FINAL` table as I am not sure how to write query to differ the above 2 cases with calculation to get expected result.

```
INSERT INTO RESULT1_CALC 
(
  SELECT T1.NAMES, T3.FR_DT, T3.TO_DT, T3.START_DT, T3.END_DT, RES.TOT_UNITS
  FROM TABLE1_NAMES T1
       JOIN (
         SELECT T2.NAMES, SUM(T2.UNITS), TOT_UNITS
         FROM TABLE2_LINES T2
         JOIN TABLE4_CODES T4
         ON T4.CD_NM = 'CODELIST'
         AND T2.CODE BETWEEN T4.B_CODE AND T4.E_CODE
         GROUP BY T2.NAMES 
       ) RES
       ON T1.NAMES = RES.NAMES
       JOIN TABLE3_DATES T3
       ON T1.NAMES = T3.NAMES
);
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO RESULT2_FINAL 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT R1.NAMES, 'ABC' EX_CD
  FROM RESULT1_CALC R1
  WHERE R1.TOT_UNITS <> (EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_DT - FR_DT))
);
COMMIT;
```

Output at the end:

- `RESULT2_FINAL` table should be populated with the help of `RESULT1_CALC` table.

| NAMES | EX_CD |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN | ABC |
| RYAN | ABC |
| TONY | ABC |

Comment: Your codes are strings so `'1000'` is between `'100'` and `'101'` when you compare strings with an alpha-numeric comparison. If you did not intend that then you should not be storing them as `VARCHAR2(4)` and should use `NUMBER(4,0)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `RESULT1_CALC` and can just insert the rows directly using the source tables into the final table:

```sql
INSERT INTO RESULT2_FINAL (names, ex_cd)
  SELECT l.names, 'ABC'
  FROM   (
           SELECT names,
                  SUM(units) AS total_units,
                  COUNT(CASE WHEN l.code = '180' THEN 1 END) AS has180,
                  COUNT(CASE WHEN l.code = '180' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS hasOther
           FROM   TABLE4_CODES c
                  INNER JOIN TABLE2_LINES l
                  ON TO_NUMBER(l.code) BETWEEN TO_NUMBER(c.b_code) AND TO_NUMBER(c.e_code)
           WHERE  c.cd_nm = 'CODELIST'
           GROUP BY names
         ) l
         INNER JOIN TABLE3_DATES d
         ON l.names =  d.names
  WHERE  (   l.has180 > 0 AND l.hasOther = 0
         AND NUMTODSINTERVAL(l.total_units, 'DAY') = d.to_dt - d.fr_dt
         )
  OR     (   l.hasOther > 0
         AND NUMTODSINTERVAL(l.total_units, 'DAY') != d.end_dt - d.start_dt
         );
```

Which, for the sample data, inserts the values:

| NAMES | EX_CD |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN | ABC |
| RYAN | ABC |
| TONY | ABC |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kc5pctC6)

Comment: Its working fine - Thank you - I have a another case scenario which is not working for this - For example, If person OLAN has CODE 201 which is eligible code then SUM(UNITS) is 1 and it compares with (TO_DT - FR_DT) formula i.e. value is 4 which is not equal so it should insert in RESULT2_FINAL table right ? but here its not inserting

Comment: @Johnbsdk10 Why should there be a row because the code `180` is not present and none of your rules say that anything should be done if code `180` is not present? We can only work from the logic you give us and if you give an incomplete set of rules then we will implement that. If you want other rules then you can implement additional `OR` clauses in the final `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Do you want me to create new question mentioning this additional rule ? or shall I edit this question it self?

Comment: @Johnbsdk10 Ideally, you would work out the logic and you would amend the query with the new logic and solve the problem yourself. If you cannot solve it yourself and the rules are simple variations on the existing rules then just edit the question; if they are significantly different from the existing rules then ask a new question.

Comment: I will edit the question now by adding new additional rule.

Comment: I have edited the question also - Can you explain me below part :  COUNT(CASE WHEN l.code = '180' THEN 1 END) AS has180,
                  COUNT(CASE WHEN l.code = '180' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS hasOther

Comment: @Johnbsdk10 Updated. That just counts the number of codes which are 180 and the number that are not 180.